# Joomla - how to catch system events

Tags: php, events, joomla, components, joomla1.7

I'm writing a joomla extension that is a component (not a plugin), however I also need to be able to detect when an article is published. I've worked out that I can do this with a plugin that catches the system event onContentChangeState, however I cannot figure out how to catch the event with a component. Any ideas?

I'm aware the easiest solution is to do it as two extension, a plugin and a component, but this is unacceptable. It must be a part of the component.

Comment: I may be wrong but I'm pretty sure that can only be done with a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Responding to events can only be done with a plugin, only [plugins can act as observers](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Developer_Overview) for trigger events. (To do otherwise would require serious hacking of the core).
2. A [Joomla Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Component) is responsible for the "main content" displayed on a page (front/back end). It does not act as an observer (while outdated the [component flow is still similar to this diagram](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Program_Flow)).
3. The common design and practice is to ship a component with it's own plugin's eg. [JCE](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/), [Virtuemart](http://virtuemart.net/), [Akeeba](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) and the list goes on...
4. From Joomla! 1.6 onwards a single [Package](http://docs.joomla.org/Package) can include multiple archives each with their own [manifest](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) i.e. a component and its related plugins.

The end result is that you can make a single extension that uses one install package for it's multiple elements.